# How to control the painting of the player

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, repaint, wm-paint

I am trying to draw something on a live video. The best way to do that in my opinion is to handle the WM_PIANT event.

My purpose is to make the player draw first and after that the application. That way I will be able to draw on the video. 
It means that I want to be notified each time before we need to paint a new frame on the window and then handle the event.

I use DirectshowNet so I am programming in C# (I have all the interfaces the c++'s API
has). I understand that the graph manager forward certain window messages to the Video Renderer such as the WM_PAINT.

How can I cause the player to draw a frame before the application and not after?

Answer (score 0):

`WM_PAINT` is not the best way, moreover it is the wrong way.

Check out `DxText` sample from DirectShow.NET library. Its description is:

> A sample application showing how to superimpose text strings on a
>   datastream.  The stream is read from an avi file.

This is so close to what you are trying to reach. An alternate approach is shown in another sample there, `BitmapMixer`:

> BitmapMixer is an example of how to draw things over a video using
>   VMR9.
>
> This sample is mainly built around the IVMRMixerBitmap9 interface.
>   This interface accept bitmaps as a GDI Device Context or as a Direct3D
>   Surface. The main advantage  of the Direct3D Surface is that it
>   enables the use of true alpha transparency. GDI DC  don't support
>   alpha bitmap and transparency is accomplished by using color keying.
>
> This sample dynamically generates bitmaps using GDI+.

Comment: I tried the BitmapMixer and it didn't work for me because I am using a Graphic object to draw on the player, I have a truly transparent panel over the window and I created graphics of that panel and then I used the hdc of the graphic object with the bitmapMixer thing and then I can't draw anymore on the graphics because the graphic object from now on is in use with someone else. Now I need to be able to draw something dynamically on the player, means that I will draw different thing on the player and they will stay there. Do you have any other idea? thanks for the help man.

Comment: DShow playback is never transparent. That is, you need to check out the samples on how to get frames out of there into `Graphic` objects and do not actually visualize the video. Instead you will use the individual frames and paint them the way you need outside of DShow.

Comment: No this isn't what i am trying to do, I am using a transparent **panel** it is a **contol** object that I made it transparent, I don't want the player to be transparent.